# I Run the code,there are no errors but nothing shows up

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I don't know whats wrong, but no errors show up, yet nothing happens...
I'm trying to represent graphically the frequency of appearance of every number (0-9) in the first 100.000 digits of pi (in a histogram, for example)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
from mpmath import *

mp.dps=100000
data = (str(pi))
plt.hist(data, bins=10, color='steelblue')
```

It should show a histogram with 10 bins and the frequency of each digit in each bin,but instead nothing shows up, but no error message is printed.

Comment: Why do you import numpy twice? Also you should maybe try `plt.show()` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to add:
plt.show()